# Command pattern with structs

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm using the command pattern to enable actions in my game to be undoable. *ICommand* defines individual commands, *ICommandHandler* does the undo-redo logic and might be decorated with other handlers like logging etc.

```
public interface ICommand
{
    void Execute();
    void Undo();
}

public interface ICommandHandler
{
    void Execute(ICommand command);
    void Undo();
    void Redo();
}

public class CommandHandler : ICommandHandler
{
    Stack<ICommand> _undoStack = new Stack<ICommand>();
    Stack<ICommand> _redoStack = new Stack<ICommand>();

    public void Execute(ICommand command)
    {
        if (command == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("command");

        command.Execute();
        _undoStack.Push(command);
        _redoStack.Clear();
    }

    public void Undo()
    {
        if (_undoStack.Count > 0)
        {
            ICommand undoCommand = _undoStack.Pop();
            undoCommand.Undo();
            _redoStack.Push(undoCommand);
        }
    }

    public void Redo()
    {
        if (_redoStack.Count > 0)
        {
            ICommand redoCommand = _redoStack.Pop();
            redoCommand.Execute();
            _undoStack.Push(redoCommand);
        }
    }
}
```

So far I'm not having any problems. Please correct me if I'm doing anything horribly wrong, but my actual questions is: Can I safely use a *struct* as a concrete command object or should I use a *class*?

```
public struct MoveCameraCommand : ICommand
{
    public CameraController cameraController;
    public Vector2 moveDelta;

    public MoveCameraCommand(CameraController controller, Vector2 moveDelta)
    {
        this.cameraController = controller;
        this.moveDelta = moveDelta;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        cameraController.Move(moveDelta);
    }

    public void Undo()
    {
        cameraController.Move(-moveDelta);
    }
}
```

I've noticed that when using a regular class, I'm generating garbage each frame with my camera, because move commands are issues very often. Since the game will be running on Android tablets, I was worried and switched to the *struct* implementation, although I've never seen it before. Might this cause other problems? Is this bad design in general? Should I not be using the command pattern for something like a camera, that is updated each frame?

Comment: "move commands are issues very often" What means 'very often'? Do you use undo/redo programatically, or is it used exclusively by the user?

Comment: Currently only the user issues commands, but there can be multiple ones within each frame. In the future I would like my AI to also issue commands; both with features like undo/redo or replay. Right now I'm generating 32 bytes of garbage each frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will not work well, I think. The only way to escape boxing on storing is to have a value type collection, so all your commands will need to be of the same type...

Also structs are very specific things, have a look below:

1. Here about [Boxing/unboxing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx).
2. Size/speed issues - try to run this [test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2407790/1219762).
3. See [Using Structs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taef578.aspx):

> When you create a struct object using the new operator, it gets created and the appropriate  constructor is called. Unlike classes, structs can be instantiated without using the new operator. In  such a case, there is no constructor call, which makes the allocation more efficient. However, the  fields will remain unassigned and the object cannot be used until all of the fields are initialized.
>
> When a struct contains a reference type as a member, the default constructor of the member must be  invoked explicitly, otherwise the member remains unassigned and the struct cannot be used. (This  results in compiler error CS0171.)
>
> There is no inheritance for structs as there is for classes. A struct cannot inherit from another  struct or class, and it cannot be the base of a class. Structs, however, inherit from the base class  Object. A struct can implement interfaces, and it does that exactly as classes do.

Comment: The boxing/unboxing turned out to be the issue here. A class would generate 32 bytes of garbage at construction, but my struct would also generate 32 bytes allocation when boxed/unboxed in my collections. So nothing won, probably only introducing other problems. Gonna stick with classes.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea - I would probably try to consider serializing command history to the couple of memory streams... Then you can create a command struct on the stack, execute, and make it persist itself to the stream. It is important to be careful about keeping references to the outside resources active though - some kind of resource locator service might help.

Just don't allocate new byte buffer for the write/read operation, BinaryWriter/BinaryReader + MemoryStream should not do it also every time.